# unable to start eclipse under java 1.8

Tags: java, eclipse

I am unable to start eclipse after a java 1.8 upgrade.  the error screenshot is attached. Here's my eclipse configuration setting.  how do I fix this?

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
-Xverify:none
```

[image]

Comment: Tried changing `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7` to 1.8 or removing it entirely?

Comment: sounds like a java installation/setup issue. What does java -version command give you? Also check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609160/eclipse-returns-error-message-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-1

Comment: A side note: no need to specify `MaxPermSize` with JDK 1.8, the support was removed (look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339707/permgen-elimination-in-jdk-8)

Comment: Don't forget to update `JAVA_HOME` and `Path`.

Comment: You are usibng a 64 bit eclipse, have you installed a 64 bit java 1.8 ?

Answer (score 3):

Did the following to run eclipse with 1.8 you change the version accordingly to 1.7

1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
4. Run $ sudo update-alternatives --config java

and enter the number for which JDK to use of your choice. Select option "0" or the one you need.

[image]

5. Check java version "java -version

Now you should be able to run Eclipse