# Java started but returned exit code =1

Tags: java, eclipse

So i recently installed eclipse for  java developers.
This one `eclipse-java-2020-06-R-win32-x86_64`
After installation i tried launching eclipse but it just says this

[image]

Anyone know how to fix
I installed JDK 14.0.4 and i have the latest java installed since its says theres no updates.

Tried to do some research on it myself some people say to make sure your java version is the same as eclipse version and when i tested i think i have 32 bit java but i have a 64bit computer and i installed 64bit eclipse. I re-installed java and nothing changed still have the error. If anyone knows how to change java from version 32bit to 64 bit that would be helpful

Comment: Means that the eclipse has not started after the installation?

Answer (score 0):

You could download the 64bit version from [oracle](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk14-archive-downloads.html#license-lightbox)
, I hope you know the new license conditions. Also make sure that the jdk bin is correctly there on the PATH in Environment Variables.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27534250/unable-to-start-eclipse-under-java-1-8) question might also provide you with an answer if the above doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

According to your logs, you're not running `JDK14` instance, but rather, something left in your `Common Files\..` folder.

Make sure you have a path to the jdk/bin/`folder added into your`PATH` environment variable.

Check it in the Windows OS, via shell, with `where java` command.