# Eclipse (cannot start JVM) Exit code=1

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

The 32bit eclipse Luna on my machine used to work without any problems with a 64bit installation of `Java 1.8 u25` on my x64 OS. To run a `GAE` sample project on my machine which required `Java 7`, I accidentally removed the `Java 8` installation from my machine. Since then, eclipse has not started at all.

Hence I installed `Java 8 u25` back which didn't help and I got the `Java was started but exited with code=13` error. I then added this to the `eclipse.ini` file after the `=vmargs` line which is indeed where the `javaw.exe` lies:
`-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\javaw.exe` (On seperate lines)

I now get the following and changing the `-Xmx` value to higher or lower doesn't make any difference: http://share.pho.to/8o9jx (Showing the error)

What could be the problem? I've read on many solution pages that I need a trio of 64 bit eclipse, OS and Java. But then, how did it work before with exactly the same settings and a 32bit eclipse?

http://share.pho.to/8o9ku (Showing java version)

Comment: Have you tried completely reinstalling Eclipse?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse returns error message "Java was started but returned exit code = 1"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609160/eclipse-returns-error-message-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-1)

Comment: I think you should try to specify your `-vm` argument before the `-vmargs` line like here [eclipse.ini](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini).

Comment: Possible dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more details see [eclipse.ini](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini)
In your Image,`-vm` should be before `-vmargs`. You are doing following wrong:

1. `-vm` you are putting at 2 place.
2. value of `-vm` on the same line.

[image]

See the below example:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20130807-1835
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:/your/Java/path/bin/javaw.exe
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m
```

Make sure you are using 64 bit eclipse version for 64bit jar.

Comment: Installed 32 bit version of Java 8 u25 and added the "--launcher.appendVmargs" line which solved the problem! Thanks.