# Eclipse won't start(no error message)

Tags: java, eclipse

I installed jdk1.7.0_79 and Eclipse for Java EE 64 bit.
When trying to run Eclipse I got the following error: **Java was started but returned exit code=1**

I followed this solution: [Eclipse returns error message "Java was started but returned exit code = 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609160/eclipse-returns-error-message-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-1)

Now, there  is no error, but Eclipse isn't starting. 
I tried all things said here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM, but when I try the other two options(**\bin\javaw.exe**, **\jre\bin\java.exe**), I get error code=1 error.
When I try to set it to **\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll** Eclipse won't start, and nothing shows up.

I tried reinstalling java and it didn't work.

Edit: I also tried adding -XX:-UseCompressedOops in eclipse.ini, but that didn't work either

Eclipse.ini content:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-XX:-UseCompressedOops
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\server\jvm.dll
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms1024
-Xmx1024m
```

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/ or https://netbeans.org/

Comment: Please add the full content of your eclipse.ini.

Comment: witch operation system are you using

Comment: You sure your Xms does not need a unit?

Comment: @Amit it does, thank you, I accidently removed it. I also deleted the .ini file, than started eclipse without it, then I returned it back and added m to Xms, when I read your comment.