# Eclipse cannot run

Tags: eclipse

When i click on the eclipse application icon,it's display below error.iam using  Eclipse Juno.JDK version 7

```
Java was started but returned exit code=1
C:/Program Files/lava/jdk1.7.0/bin/javaw.me 
-Dosgi.requiredlavaVersion=1.5 
-Xms40m 
-Xmx512m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m 
-jar E: SLUT \ Research \soft\ eclipseV\ plugins/org.eclipse.equinox. 502.jar 
-os win32 
-ws win32 
-arch x86 
-showsplash 
-launcher E: SLUT Rmearch \ soft\ eclipse\ eclipse.exe 
-name Eclipse 
--launcher.library E: SLUT \ Rearch \soft\ eclipse\Nplugins/org.eclipse.equinox. .x86_1.1.100.v20110502 eclipse_1406.d11
 -startup E\SLUT Rmearch \ soft\ eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox. 502.jar 
--launcher.overrideVmargs -exitdata 1694_128 -product org.eclipse.epp.packagejee.product 
-vm C:/Program File/Java/jdk1.7.0/bin/javaw.exe
-vmargs 
-Dosgi.requiredjavaVersion=1.5 
-Xms4Om
 -Xmx512m -XXMaxPermSize=256m 
-jar E: SLUT Research‘soft\ eclipse\\ plugins/org.eclipse.equinox. 502.jar 
    launcher 1.2.0.v20110 launcher.win32.win32 launcher 1.2.0.v20110 launcher 1.2.0.v20110
```

Comment: this is a PROGRAMMING community, - unlike superuser.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609160/eclipse-returns-error-message-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-1

Comment: Is this the correct output? There are multiple parent directories shown for what should be a single installation of Eclipse,