# eclipse keep crashing with exit code 1

Tags: java, eclipse

I have been learning java for a while but this problem just occurred a few days ago.

I have tried the following methods and none have worked:

1. Adding `-Xint` to the `ini` file
2. Adding `--XX:-UseCompressedOops` to the `ini` file
3. Adding `-XX:+UseCompressedOops` to the `ini` file
4. Running as Administrator
5. `-vm`

`c:/wherever/java/jdk1.6.0_21/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll`

I think this is a lot to read through. Thank you so much!!

### Here is the error message

[image: Eclipse error]

### Here is what's in my eclipse.ini

```
 -startup
 plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
 --launcher.library
 plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
 -product
 org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
 --launcher.defaultAction
 openFile
 --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
 256M
 -showsplash
 org.eclipse.platform
 --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
 256m
 --launcher.defaultAction
 openFile
 --launcher.appendVmargs
 -vmargs
 -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
 -Xms256m
 -Xmx1024m
```

### Here is the info in the .log

```
!SESSION 2015-12-15 09:42:29.142 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.5.1.M20150904-0015
java.version=1.7.0_79
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2015-12-15 09:42:34.222
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session;  refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2015-12-15 09:42:51.941
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\WeiLi'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.
```

Comment: Did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609160/eclipse-returns-error-message-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-1 ?

Comment: Exit code 1 isn't very helpful; however, there's a log file in the workspace that you can add to your post or on pastebin; that will help us better locating the problem.

Comment: What version of eclipse are you using?

Comment: @user I already tried their solutions but it didn't work

Comment: @RobertoLinares I am using the Eclipse Mars. 1(4.5.1)

Comment: @TassosBassoukos just added!

Comment: @Mr. Polywhirl Thanks for the formatting !

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you're specifying a 1.6 VM in the .ini (why do you need to do that? it's 8 years old by now, just let the system VM run) but there's an `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7` in the error message; further, do you have a C:\Windows\System32\javaw.exe, and what version is it?

Comment: I have no ideas why it's set up like that. I installed it a few months ago the way it's taught in a java tutorial.   It worked perfectly fine for the past few months but it started crashing a few days ago.        I do have that file and the version is: 7.0.790.15