# Eclipse Returned Exit Code 1 Eclipse INI File

Tags: java, eclipse

I installed Eclipse recently. I've been messing around with the ini file trying to actually open the program. I keep getting the following error. I've seen multiple posts on this but I can't seem to figure out what the problem is with my version.

My eclipse ini file looks like the following:

```
    -startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
-vmargs
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

When I click on Eclipse.exe, I get an error message back saying:

> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

I created a backup just in case I don't fix it. Below is my error message

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZnhq.png]

I installed a 64 bit version of Eclipse, because when I check for the program under Task manager it's not marked with a *32

I have two paths that I can point to, but eclipsepedia points to the .dll file within the jdk foler.
[image]

Comment: Unzip a fresh copy and see if it works.

Comment: +1 @Thorbjørn - Ross - keep backups when playing with this stuff.  I'm not familiar with all the details but play with one parameter at a time.

Comment: ... and post text as such and not screenshot

Comment: Is there an exception in  `workspace/.metadata/.log` ?

Comment: I wouldn't know where to find that?

Comment: I think it has something to do with your Java version

Comment: Do you have Jdk installed on your machine?

Comment: Here is the link which discusses the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609160/eclipse-returns-error-message-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-1

Comment: Yeah I changed the path because I had an error code 1, so the elipsepedia page said to do: C:\Development\Java\64bit\jdk1.7.0_09\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll

Comment: Finally it worked! I had originally installed the 64 bit version of Eclipse, then the 1.8 JDK 32 bit version (these two must be the same version 32/64). I changed where the eclipse.ini was pointing towards in regards to the javaw. Now it points to the 64 bit version.