# Scala with ScalaFx: invalid or missing dependency

Tags: scala, sbt, scalafx

After I switched from SDK Version `scala-SDK-4.4.1-vfinal-2.11-win32.win32.x86_64` to Version `scala-SDK-4.5.0-vfinal-2.11-win32.win32.x86_64` I´m getting some error messages in eclipse:

[image: eclipse errors]

Full error message:

> missing or invalid dependency
>   detected while loading class file 'Alert.class'. Could not access term
>   Alert in package javafx.scene.control, because it (or its
>   dependencies) are missing. Check your build definition for missing or
>   conflicting dependencies. (Re-run with `-Ylog-classpath` to see the
>   problematic classpath.) A full rebuild may help if 'Alert.class' was
>   compiled against an incompatible version of
>   javafx.scene.control. ageofscala      Unknown Scala Problem

I´m getting 23 errors of that.

I´m using scalaFx in my project. Before I switched to the newer SDK, the project was running perfectly. Now it doesn´t even run with the older SDK version. The reason because I switched to the newer SDK was this error: [Eclipse returns error message “Java was started but returned exit code = 1”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609160/eclipse-returns-error-message-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-1) So I added this line to the eclipse.ini file:

`-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll`

And here is my build.sbt :

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.2.1"
libraryDependencies += "com.github.nscala-time" %% "nscala-time" % "2.12.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.4"
libraryDependencies += "com.lambdaworks" %% "jacks" % "2.3.3"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" % "play_2.11" % "2.5.3"
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-swing" % "2.11.0-M7"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalafx" % "scalafx_2.11" % "8.0.92-R10"
```

Are there some version problems or something else? I tried to update the project to the newest Scala version (`"2.12.1"`) and newest ScalaFx version (`"org.scalafx" %% "scalafx" % "8.0.102-R11"`) but with no success...
Can anyone please help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alerts were added in Java 8u40. You have 8u25. You need to update your version of Java to more recent one.