# Error:could not create java virtual machine

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse version :eclipse-jee-oxygen-3a-win32-x86_64
java : jdk1.7.0_79
System Info :

[image]

Eclipse error :

[image]

eclipse configuration settings file :

> -startup plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
>   --launcher.library plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.551.v20171108-1834
>   -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
>   -showsplash org.eclipse.epp.package.common
>   --launcher.defaultAction openFile
>   --launcher.defaultAction openFile-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\javaw.exe
>   --launcher.appendVmargs
>   -vmargs
>   -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
>   -Dosgi.instance.area.default=@user.home/eclipse-workspace
>   -XX:+UseG1GC
>   -XX:+UseStringDeduplication
>   --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
>   -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7-Xms256m
>   -Xmx512m
>   --add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609160/eclipse-returns-error-message-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609160/eclipse-returns-error-message-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-1) Actually what you are looking for.

Comment: i tried almost everything in the internet already. Please let me know if you could check with the information provided in the question and find the issue in that.

Comment: Eclipse Oxygen requires at least Java 8 to run even if you set `osgi.requiredJavaVersio` to `1.7`.

Comment: Java 8 or higher should be used as per @howlger see here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation#Eclipse_4.7_.28Oxygen.29

Comment: Thanks for all your help. It Worked after java 8 installation.i like to understand how the changes made to eclipse.ini reflects in the eclipse error message image i posted. i had added -vm... to eclipse.ini but the -vm values in the error image is different from the one i entered into the eclipse.ini

Comment: `-vm` have to be specified directly before `-vmargs`: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse returns error message "Java was started but returned exit code = 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609160/eclipse-returns-error-message-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-1)

Comment: Hey guys, if it is fixed, then kindly please, put the answer instead the comment, and mark it as solved, for proper filtering, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Eclipse Oxygen requires at least Java 8 to run](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation#Eclipse_4.7_.28Oxygen.29)** even if `osgi.requiredJavaVersion` is set to `1.7`.

In `eclipse.ini` the parameter `-vm` must be used directly before `-vmargs`. For details see Eclipse Wiki: [Eclipse.ini - Specifying the JVM](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM).