# Trying to install eclipse, but I get an "Java was started but returned exit code = 1"

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm starting to learn programming and I'm thinking the root of this problem is that  eclipse doesn't know where my Java is actually located, but I can't seem to figure how to fix that. I have a 64 bit java jdk version 1.8.0_192 but I get this [error].

The file path for the java jdk would be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_192`

error:

[image]

Comment: Try the answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609160/eclipse-returns-error-message-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-1). This might fix it

Comment: If the Jdk is x64 then why it is installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\?

Comment: @sand I tried that method but I get " Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:Progam Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_192\jre\server\jvm.dll" ".

Comment: @Eugen Covaci I'm actually not sure, when I downloaded the installer it defaulted to installing there. Should I move to Program files?

Comment: In command prompt  run: `java -version` and post the output.

Comment: @EugenCovaci The output was

 java version "1.8.0_192"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_192-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.192-b12, mixed mode)

Comment: What Eclipse version do you have? x86 or 64?

Comment: @EugenCovaci I believe it is x86 since the rar file I download off their website was named "eclipse-dsl-2018-09-win32-x86_64"

Comment: Download and install JDK 8 64 bit

Comment: @EugenCovaci Just to clarify, JDK 8 64 bit would be the Windows x86 off this website right? Becasue that's what I have: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: No, it's Windows x64

Comment: @EugenCovaci Well I feel pretty stupid hahaha. Thank you, that seemed to fix it!

Answer (score 2):

When installing, your zip file and saved file should be at the same place. As a precautionary measure, do it all on your desktop and that may help solve the problem.