# Eclipse fails to open and gives me a very long error. [Java]

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime-error

I am attempting to run eclipse (4.15 I believe) and after opening the program it gives this error window.

[image]

I believe it is a version problem. However, I cannot find anything in regards to my version being not up to date or too advanced. I am running java 1.8.0.

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609160/eclipse-returns-error-message-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-1

Comment: It depends on java 32/64 bit and eclipse 32/64 bit and windows 32/64 bit. Kindly mention all 3 details then I will tell how to resolve it.

Comment: Yes I looked at that question and tried many different answers however none of them worked. Thank you.

Comment: @PythonNerd it is version compatibility issue. Hence I asked you to provide all informtion.

Comment: I have 32 bit java, I believe 64 bit eclipse (not sure how to check) and 64 bit windows.

is the java version the problem?

Comment: @PythonNerd in that case you need to use java 64 bit. Try with that and let me know if you still encounter the same issue.

Comment: Seems to be finally working for now! TYSM everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use one of the following combinations:**

- 32-bit OS, 32-bit JDK, 32-bit Eclipse (32-bit only)
- 64-bit OS, 32-bit JDK, 32-bit Eclipse
- 64-bit OS, 64-bit JDK, 64-bit Eclipse (64-bit only)