# Eclipse is not opening? showing a error. I already installed Java Jdk file and assigned path to the eclipse

Tags: eclipse-installer

[image: Error_image]

The error is shown in the image.
I'm using windows 8.1

1. I installed Eclipse and then installed Java Jdk 14
2. I edited the path and gave the java/jdk/bin path to it.
3. after that when i'm trying to open then it's showing this error.

Comment: possible a duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609160/eclipse-returns-error-message-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-1

Comment: try to use Intellij Idea, its much better.