# Eclipse Returns Error message While Installing in Windows10

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

While Installing the Eclipse I have the following error "**Java was started but returned exit code=1**"

Note: My question is already asked by someone but it is quite different.

[Eclipse returns error message "Java was started but returned exit code = 1"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18609160/eclipse-returns-error-message-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-1)

[image]

Here is my **eclipse.ini** file
[image]

Comment: Looks like a 32 bit Java with a 64 bit Eclipse - they must both be 64 bits.

Comment: Which version of Java do you have installed?